# 4d mapping in C++ with tuple

Tags: c++, dictionary

This is somewhat similar to this problem [4d mapping in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288781/4d-mapping-in-c) and one of my previous questions on maps in C++ [Use a map with the map name defined by a string C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58304992/use-a-map-with-the-map-name-defined-by-a-string-c)

I have a code that looks like this (that does not work and stops at the line giving input to the map):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<string, //Volkswagen (car brand)
        map<string, //series
            map<int, //in this example 1
                tuple<string, string>>>> mapMapMap;

    string myCarmapMapMap = "Volkswagen";
    int Number = 1;

    mapMapMap[myCarmapMapMap]["3 series"][Number] = {90, 20};,

    string Output;
    Output.assign(get<0>(mapMapMap[myCarmapMapMap].find("3 series")->second));
    cout << "\n" << "------------" << "\n" << Output << "\n"<< "------------" << "\n";
}
```

What I want to do is to assign two values to `Volkswagen`, `3 series`, `1` and then be able to call it like:
`Volkswagen -> 3 series -> 1 -> <0> (value 1).`

This is the error message I get:
`|19|error: expected primary-expression before ',' token|`

I have also tried:

`mapMapMap.insert({myCarmapMapMap, "3 series", Number, {"90", "20"}});`

But it does not work either. How do I combine a 4d map with a tuple?

Comment: You expect a `tuple<string, string>` but you are trying to assign integers `90` and `20`.

Comment: The error message you get should contain enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: True, but putting "" around did not help.

Comment: Then you need to tell us what you mean by "it does not work". Do you get build errors? Please copy-paste the full and complete error output into the question. And please refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Thanks, I updated with the error message.

Comment: `mapMapMap[myCarmapMapMap].find("3 series")->second` is a `map<int, tuple<string, string>>`. You're one level short on the lookups.

Comment: Like this then? `Output.assign(get<0>(((mapMapMap[myCarmapMapMap].find("3 series"))[Number])->second));`

Comment: @KGB91 No. `mapMapMap[myCarmapMapMap].find("3 series")` is a map iterator; you can't index it. Stop guessing, think about the types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your assignment so it can actually form a `tuple<string, string>` (note the quotation signs on the right hand side):

```
mapMapMap[myCarmapMapMap]["3 series"][Number] = {"90", "20"};
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/vxd0GL)

Also, remove the `,` at the end of the line.

Your query can, probably, be fixed by including the `Number` again, like:

```
string output = get<0>(mapMapMap[myCarmapMapMap].find("3 series")->second[Number]);
```

Comment: That helped, but I still cannot search for the content I want. `|22|error: no matching function for call to 'get(std::map<int, std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&)'|`

Comment: Yes, because that query gives you a `map<int, tuple<string, string>>` and not a `tuple<string, string>`. That's why `get` is not working.

Comment: How do I write the last step? See comment above for my try...